# Change default column name 'id' when validating

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to validate an email field so that I make sure it's unique, but not in a row with a certain id, which I do like so:

```
'email' => 'required|email|unique:seller_user,email,'.$seller_id,
```

That works, but it automatically searches for a column named `id`, whereas in my table that column is actually called `seller_id`, so how can I change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the field to search using the fourth parameter to the rule:

```
'email' => 'required|email|unique:seller_user,email,'.$seller_id.',seller_id',
```